# NodeJS запуск кода

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаюсь запустить простейший пример, описанный в [документации Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-beginners-tutorial), но натыкаюсь на следующую ошибку:

```
C:\Users\CurrentUser\projs\jsPractice\helloworld\app.js:1
��v

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Делаю все четко по инструкции, для установки Nodejs использовал [следующую документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows).

Версии nvm и node соответственно

```
> nvm version
1.1.8
> node -v
v16.10.0
> npm -version
7.24.0
```

Пытался использовать LTS-версию (14.17.6) — результат аналогичный.

Upd.
Непосредственно js-код

```
var msg = 'hello tutorial';
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: `app.js` в студию. пишет же, что символ там встретил, которого там быть не должно

Comment: Сохраните файл в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните `app.js` в кодировке `UTF-8`